# How do you use i18n with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, internationalization, pootle

We are about to start building our web app in Node.js and I would like to be ready for i18n so I'm looking for your experience with building Node.js apps where the text is translatable.

Preferably I'd like to use a tool like [Pootle](http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/pootle/index) via Git or other if you have any recommendations.

Comment: as mentioned in accepted solution [i18next - i18n for node.js or javascript](http://i18next.com/node) adds all features needed fpr proper i18n plus has a web ui for translation.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125560/referenceerror-intl-is-not-defined-in-node-js -  concerning EcmaScript 402 support in Node.

Comment: Also there is [an example](https://github.com/efkan/node-intl-polyfill-example)  regarding how to implement i18n basically. You might visit .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a number of [i18n modules](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-i18n) you can use in your application, but you can create your own if you want.

For example create a folder /languages and inside it create en.js, fr.js etc

**it.js**

```
module.exports = {
  "name": "nome",
  "age": "eta",
  .. etc
}
```

The important thing is to set a default language and make a language select bar somewhere in your site. When the user chooses another language (and not English) in your app you do something like this:

```
app.get('/lang/:ln', function (req, res, next) {
  // remember the user's chosen language
  req.session.language = req.params.ln;
});
```

Then you can have a language helper function like so:

```
translate = function (language, text) {
  // language array contains all the languages
  return language_array[language].text;
}
// example: translate(req.session.language, "age")
```

Comment: i18n in nodejs with [i18next](http://i18next.com/node) works well. i just added a ui to translate resources in web i18next.com/pages/ext_webtranslate.html

Comment: But how do you add date/currency translation?
Internationalization isn't just about translating text strings :-P

Comment: @kanyee those string values can also just as easily be functions.

Comment: How do you load i.e. it.js into language_array? Node n00b here sry.