# ReferenceError: Intl is not defined in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, internationalization

I'm trying to construct a `new Intl.Collator()` object in Node.js.

Does anyone know why the [`Intl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) object wouldn't be present in a Node runtime?

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator), it is specified as a Namespace by ECMAScript, so I don't see why it wouldn't be there.

Comment: Because that module isn't bundled in Node :P

Comment: Why not? Isn't it bundled in V8?

Comment: Apparently not. since `var Intl = require('Intl');` doesn't work and neither does `new Intl.Collator()`

Comment: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6371

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately node currently (as of version 0.10, at time of writing) does not support the ECMA-402 `Intl` object unless you perform a custom compile of node, which is documented in the node.js [Readme](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/README.md).

> With libicu i18n support:
>
> ```
> svn checkout --force --revision 214189 \
>    http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/deps/third_party/icu46 \
>    deps/v8/third_party/icu46
> ./configure --with-icu-path=deps/v8/third_party/icu46/icu.gyp
> make
> ```
>
> make install

If compiling a custom build of node is not an option or the idea fills you with dread, a workaround is to use the **[intl module](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js)**, a Javascript polyfill which covers much of the EMCA-402 standard, except for the `Intl.Collator`, the reasons for which are covered in the project Readme file.

Using the module is straight-forward:

```
npm install intl --save
```

Then in your node code:

```
var Intl = require('intl');
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat("de-DE").format(12345678));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, and see the ticket https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6371 mentioned above. This is considered a 'minority use' feature. but I want to work on getting it enabled by default. And then we can revise the answer to this question.

Comment: This has since landed in Node 0.12 and io.js 1.0 https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7676#issuecomment-68811475

Comment: Also, please note Node does not recomment building ICU from Chromium: https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/Intl 
Building using Chromium's ICU

Note: not recommended! This build is missing some locales, is an older revision, and has a larger output size. It is documented here for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Since io.js was merged into Node, it should be possible to use Intl in newer versions of Node (available in io.js from v3.1.0).

> - intl: Intl support using small-icu is now enabled by default in builds (Steven R. Loomis) [#2264](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/2264).
>
>   - [String#normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) can now be used for unicode normalization.
>   - The [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) object and various String and Number methods are present, but only support the English locale.
>   - For support of all locales, node must be built with [full-icu](https://github.com/nodejs/node#build-with-full-icu-support-all-locales-supported-by-icu).

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2015-08-18-version-310-fishrock123

Answer (score 1):

Node 0.12 has included support to Intl, but it comes with only a subset of ICU locales (i.e.: English). You need to build Node with flags for full ICU (or any subset you need). Long instructions for ICU build here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/Intl

I would recommend reading the FormatJS documentation:
http://formatjs.io/

And especially the Intl Polyfill

https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js

```
var areIntlLocalesSupported = require('intl-locales-supported');

var localesMyAppSupports = [
    /* list locales here */
];

if (global.Intl) {
    // Determine if the built-in `Intl` has the locale data we need.
    if (!areIntlLocalesSupported(localesMyAppSupports)) {
        // `Intl` exists, but it doesn't have the data we need, so load the
        // polyfill and replace the constructors we need with the polyfill's.
        require('intl');
        Intl.NumberFormat   = IntlPolyfill.NumberFormat;
        Intl.DateTimeFormat = IntlPolyfill.DateTimeFormat;
    }
} else {
    // No `Intl`, so use and load the polyfill.
    global.Intl = require('intl');
}
```

Intl.js does not (and will never) implement Intl.Collator. For this one, you really need to rely on Node 0.12 built with your required locales.

Comment: Update: the `full-icu` module will install full data,  see [full-icu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/full-icu) 
and also [#3460](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3460)

Comment: Is it save to add?: Number.prototype.toLocaleString = function(locale) {
   return Intl.NumberFormat(locale).format(this);
  };
  Date.prototype.toLocaleString = function(locale) {
   return Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale).format(this);
  };

Comment: For the standard Node 0.12+ build with `Intl` support, any formatting will work only for the limited locales that come pre-built. If you want all locales, you need to build Node with `full-icu`. I wouldn't mess with the prototypes, because you will overwrite the standard behavior.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution for React / Next JS

> Reference Error: Intl is not defined

The error is due to the browser compatibility. [See the same here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#browser_compatibility)

**Error found in:**  Mobile, Android, MiuiBrowser 9.7.3

Add any other envs in the comments that are not in the above list/ Browser Compatibility table

### Fix:

Use a polyfill

```
import IntlPolyfill from "intl";

// import desired or required locale
import "intl/locale-data/jsonp/en";
import "intl/locale-data/jsonp/en-IN";
```

function that returns Polyfill if `Intl` is undefined

```
function getIntl() {
  if (typeof Intl !== "undefined") {
    return Intl;
  }

  return IntlPolyfill;
}

const CustomIntl = getIntl();
```

Usage:

```
const number = 123456;

const enFormatted = new CustomIntl.NumberFormat("en").format(number);
console.log("enFormatted: ", enFormatted); // 123,456

const enINFormatted = new CustomIntl.NumberFormat("en-IN").format(number);
console.log("enINFormatted: ", enINFormatted); // 1,23,456
```

---

[image: Edit intl-polyfill]